# How can I apply setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END) on EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

The effect I want to achieve is shown as below:
[image]

I expect that when the button is clicked and if the text length is longer than the `EditText's` width, the "..." be appended at the end.

I tried in 2 ways.

**One is like this:**

```
 if (str != null && edt.getWidth() <= edt.getTextSize() * str.length()) {
      String dotsString = str.substring(0, (int)(edt.getWidth()/ 
                           edt.getTextSize()) - 1) + "...";
      edt.setText(dotsString);
     }
```

It looks fine, but when the text is mixed by different languages, Chinese and English characters, for instance, the result will not neet my expectation.

**And the another way I tried is like this:**

```
TextView edtTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
edtTv.setSingleLine(true);
edtTv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
edtTv.setText(edtTv.getText().toString());
```

But it does not work.

I'm so confused! Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Are you asking about EditText or TextView?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with EditText ellipsis not working is caused by horizontal scrolling. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30728274/2894819)

Comment: The answer you're referring to is about TextView

Comment: EditText extends TextView, so it refers to both